# Why does my loop only append the last iteration over and over when appending to a large dataFrame?

Tags: python, pandas

I'm working on a data project and I use requests in order to fetch page 1, append the contents to a dataFrame, then fetch page 2, append the contents to a dataFrame and so on.

When I loop 500 times, everything is fine and the code prints every wine name and creates a .xlsx file of all of the information that I want.  However, when I loop 2000 times, it ends up only printing the last iteration of the loop over and over, and the data in the .xlsx file is the last iteration over and over with none of the data before it. It's almost like it's overwriting the data it receives with the last loop.  Is this a memory issue? What is going on?

```
import requests
import pandas as pd
from pandas.io.json import json_normalize

headers = {
    'accept': 'application/json',
    'accept-encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br',
    'accept-language': 'en-US,en;q=0.9',
    'content-type': 'application/json',
    'cookie': '__auc=c5035a4c16fd460dc07ce0577a8; _ga=GA1.2.1675266079.1579816115; _gid=GA1.2.130433663.1579816115; _hjid=d8db62c6-5395-4792-b978-f8acad779132; G_ENABLED_IDPS=google; __stripe_mid=9c010cef-ed83-4d45-b43c-c503185f7286; deal_merchant_context=bjlQcWtzZjRUOVUwSkd2a2Q5UVZaQT09LS1iS21HdHlvc3dnTFozMUk0Vm4zYUd3PT0%3D--af41bf85604d65df31e1a087856436a7458f8fa0; recently_viewed=dFJZL28wSlpBbWZxM0lhV29Ndmo1eG1uT2locmYzSnFRNnZ5RTV3VHoyY1NkZkFOY2dBSzhpcDl0N3paaE9Cakk4ajR3aXVsbnU2S0pHaXR3MGkvNzhJb21rckpxR3pEVmg3NktJSXBLaXpXUkRqdHlPOGJBNm9ld1dEcHVNMEtDbGtlSHdrMUd5ZGh5dnVZL1AvbFh6THVUbHp5Smx5MXlGZU9iREtzREpKRVZ3ckhEKytKRDM2RTlFNlNvTEh3cE9xM200OTc4K2ZLTk1EU1VCK09BS3NabVo2TG5qWmg5SGRFWndTZjNLWXZpVXRtalhvemRKM2dyb1JNMDhKQXJxbEdIb0lpU25RUHp1Si9wSElrdFE9PS0tc0UzQ1gyeDViZTBTRTRZVjJJdm5ZUT09--c5812ca2bd7329c13efd31f5d2857d2d350cca4f; client_cache_key=bjRJRU50Smp4QllWZWZSZEN5U0dSaFZtZUdYUFhLeU1waVNxWlZzeVZMcz0tLVh5Tk43Q2R0OGxUL3hhdU9sM25rTUE9PQ%3D%3D--dcb0317e19a27dd55c032f3469330257f231aa18; __asc=1d3a125116fda03bf8ec3ab44e7; _derived_epik=dj0yJnU9cTREcURvekxVdWgxV0hwRkVNdS01OHdydVlVV0NqdEkmbj04MFFOQ09QUnduSFMtX0t4eHZjXzJ3Jm09NyZ0PUFBQUFBRjRyaGhR; _hp2_id.3503103446=%7B%22userId%22%3A%221682039594803097%22%2C%22pageviewId%22%3A%224355036978439434%22%2C%22sessionId%22%3A%227569355054565139%22%2C%22identity%22%3Anull%2C%22trackerVersion%22%3A%224.0%22%7D; _hp2_ses_props.3503103446=%7B%22r%22%3A%22https%3A%2F%2Fwww.vivino.com%2Fexplore%3Fe%3DeJwdyjkKgDAURdHdvFKMQ_k6dyBWIvKNMQSMShIcdq_Y3NNcH1hmNbzbqHJ4uVnl0A-7FvpLg4MKduEpwZkkK_aJQZLbbBzlNEGswc7ZRI0r9cM3_xSI1PICdrAezQ%3D%3D%22%2C%22ts%22%3A1579910677732%2C%22d%22%3A%22www.vivino.com%22%2C%22h%22%3A%22%2Fexplore%22%2C%22q%22%3A%22%3Fe%3DeJwdyjkKgDAURdHdvFKMQ_k6dyBWIvKNMQSMShIcdq_Y3NNcH1hmNbzbqHJ4uVnl0A-7FvpLg4MKduEpwZkkK_aJQZLbbBzlNEGswc7ZRI0r9cM3_xSI1PICdrAezQ%3D%3D%22%7D; _ruby-web_session=WEVrV0tKSTF0WENUelFEbkJhNWcvQ1FLREszUCthSHYxQlZ3U1FLcE1UOTNNMHRyUmhDMmNobzlnUnZTZ2FJOXlwTWcrRUx1SzhuV29xYjJVUHBSSERBclplVkwybWxDRjFqT1FyOXFZQy9lRlg5dzB6RnpMZU5nWVJZVk1Xd3JIZm9MdHJVY3hPN2hobElVaXA4UzJLMC9IdFZ2ejBiV3pObTZ5Z1c2dTNaQllhWHdwQ1MrNW41cnlPWk5PcFIvVmxXd0F2VEVaT1dNZ0xqbHdtRTlNdkRsWVcvTEY1eGJSL2J6M254YTJIRm1HaHdob3NEa3hISHBpa3NHR0pVU0FLUzUwSWZMa2xGVVJRMklEVC9DdjRUd0drOWVJK3JkUE5aWkJ5bjF5N0kwcXo0amRUbUc0ZDdnT1cyRTJIbVl2MkZqL1Z0MTh2c09jeG9BWGVXa1Q4QWpvWDRwLzF4cXBjVXp4cmhDR2lFSXNyT2l4ZGtKK3liUUZydGd6ODhILS1DNGtFR1p5dm9QYlF3NkxtaGZnVUFBPT0%3D--d12cf4a96fb3bdab033a69f023265c2d009df0d4if-none-match: W/"0d29d1e750e26bd001dfced1286a95f6"',
    'referer': 'https://www.vivino.com/explore?e=eJwdyjkKgDAURdHdvFKMQ_k6dyBWIvKNMQSMShIcdq_Y3NNcH1hmNbzbqHJ4uVnl0A-7FvpLg4MKduEpwZkkK_aJQZLbbBzlNEGswc7ZRI0r9cM3_xSI1PICdrAezQ==',
    'sec-fetch-mode': 'cors',
    'sec-fetch-site': 'same-origin',
    'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_13_6) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/79.0.3945.130 Safari/537.36',
    'x-requested-with': 'XMLHttpRequest'
}

p = {
    'country_code': 'US',
    'currency_code': 'USD',
    'grape_filter': 'varietal',
    'min_rating': '1',
    'order_by': 'ratings_average',
    'order': 'desc',
    'page': '1',
    'price_range_max': '500',
    'price_range_min': '0',
    'wine_type_ids[]': '1',
    'wine_type_ids[]': '2',
}



def main():

    a = int(p['page'])
    df = pd.DataFrame()

    while a < 500:
        p['page'] = str(a)
        a += 1

        try:
            r = requests.get(
                'https://www.vivino.com/api/explore/explore?country_code=MX&currency_code=MXN&grape_filter=varietal&min_rating=3.5&order_by=ratings_average&order=desc&page=1&price_range_max=400&price_range_min=100&wine_type_ids[]=1&wine_type_ids[]=2',
                headers=headers, params=p)
            complete_json = r.json()
            print('success')

            # normalize and clean up the data a little bit before sending to the dataframe
            df_data = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(json_normalize(complete_json['explore_vintage']['matches']), orient='columns')
            df = df.append(df_data)

        except:
            False

    df.to_excel('first_500_wines.xlsx', encoding='utf8')
    print(df['vintage.name'].to_csv(index=False))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: try changing `df = df.append(df_data)` to `df = pd.concat([df, df_data])`

Comment: @kenan That didn't work, same thing happened.

Comment: It’s always best to make except statements are specific as possible.

Comment: Are you using request.get properly?  I never actually used it but you are populating the params in the url where params will do that for you. In the url you have &page=1 which seems static.  My reference: https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/master/user/quickstart/

Comment: debug by putting a `break` in your except statement, see if it fails along the way

Comment: @kenan I think the issue was that as the 'page' count got to the last page, it kept requesting the last page and appending it. I didn't know what the last page was. So, I've added an if statement that breaks out of the loop when an item in the current list's count is greater than 1. I will post that if after this run it works. EDIT: if it has to call itself to check whether a string matches, it will take forever. hmm.